# Sliding 1 seekbar is causing Both Seekbars to change thumbs

Tags: android, seekbar

This is a strange one. I have 2 seek bars and I have established a listener for both. However when I slide the thumbbar for one seekbar - it updates that seekbar AND it also moves the thumb of the second seekbar.

If I move the thumb on the second seekbar - it only changes the second sekbar NOT the first.

If I remove the listener for the first seekbar - I get the same problem.

I have attached code pertiaing to the seekbar listeners. mSeekBarA is the first one. mSeekBarB is the second.

```
      mSeekBarA.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
      { 

           @Override 
           public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
           { 

           } 

           @Override 
           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
           { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

           } 

           @Override 
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
           { 
           On_SFX_Volume_Change(progress);

           } 
      }); 


      mSeekBarB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
      { 

           @Override 
           public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
           { 

           } 

           @Override 
           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
           { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

           } 

           @Override 
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
           { 
               On_MUS_Volume_Change(progress);

           } 
      });
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

How did you instantiate these sliders? I bet that they are actually referring to the same instance. Possibly you added the same slider to the layout instead of adding the each one individually.

Comment: I created them individually. I think that the fact that the second bar works independently AND each is a different color is proof they are different objects. The first bar is controlling BOTH bars, while the second is only controlling itself.

Comment: It was the drawable I assigned to the seekbars. I had assigned the same drawable for each of the seekbars thumb drawing.           Drawable d3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.xml.thumb_drawable);
          mSeekBarA.setThumb(d3);
          mSeekBarB.setThumb(d3);
Once I corrected this - it worked fine.